# BSOD occured + computer stalling

Tags: windows-7, bsod

my computer specs pastebin.com/P9y7eP21

I have a windows 7 64 bit.  I've had it for a long time without issue.
A few days ago I wanted to swap out my i5 cpu for an i7 cpu.

Once the i7 was in I was experiencing "stalls" where I might launch a program and the computer doesn't do anything.  I could try launching other programs and they too do not launch during this "stall" period.  Then at some point, the computer launches everything all together.   The cpu usage shows 0% during this time and then it spikes up when it launches all the programs I basically queued up.

So for a while I thought something was wrong with the i7.  Then I swapped out the i7 to use the i5 again.  And then I had a stall again.

So I did something bad when I was changing cpus or something...
I don't know if I made some static on the motherboard/ram/video card/etc.
Or maybe changing cpus caused a problem.  (I even reinstalled windows which was troublesome with the stalling. Yes the stalling even happened during windows installtion.)

But now I might have a clue to what's wrong.  I had a BSOD.   I never found the XML file that was mentioned in the message after restarting the computer.
I did find the dump file.

Can someone take a look and tell me what happened to cause the bsod?

I would be very grateful for an answer, I'm so stressed out by these problems.

download my dump file:

filedropper
http://www.filedropper.com/minidump

puush
https://puu.sh/qH5cA/b3c97ea700.zip

Comment: Which i7 did you put in your computer?

Comment: Intel Core i7-2600 Sandy Bridge Quad-Core 3.4GHz (3.8GHz Turbo Boost) LGA 1155 95W BX80623I72600 Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 2000 http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115071

Comment: I'd have to see a picture of your CPU mount. I'm wondering if you messed up a pin on the board or something?

Comment: I was very keen on checking pins and what not each time I removed the cpu. I don't think a pin is bent. I'm pretty careful taking out and putting in cpus.

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg gives the following information:

```
INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR (a0)
The power policy manager experienced a fatal error.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000009, A fatal error occured while preparing the hibernate file.
Arg2: ffffffffc0000185, Status code
Arg3: 0000000000000001, Mirroring phase
Arg4: 0000000000000000
```

`c0000185` is an I/O error. You have 3 hard disks and a DVD drive installed. I'd try removing the ones that don't contain the Windows OS and then try again.

If that does not help, check if you can replace the system disk. This seems to be likely, since you experience the issues during the Windows installation and the hibernate file is typically on the system partition.

Comment: "replace the system disk"  By this you mean replace the hard drive that contains the OS?   or replace the windows OS installation CD?

Comment: @ShakovSkanton: the hard disk